# Run bash script between time variables

Tags: bash, variables, time, cron, schedule

I need to run some task at a dynamic time presented in the **variable** (which value is in **HH.mm.ss** format) **+ 2 minutes** from its value and less than **5 minutes**. Then I could add this job to crontab to schedule it for every minute and I hope that the script will run when the time variable syncs the current time + 2 (or a bit more) minutes (but no more than 5 minutes).

Thank you.

Update:
Thanks to l0b0, all that is left is to find a way to substract 2 minutes from **HH.mm.ss** variable to get for example 05:28:00 after substraction from var 05:30:00. I think it must be somehow simple. Thanks for help.

Comment: You can schedule it to run every minute and perform that check (if it's within 2 and 5 minutes from some other time). Every other run will just fail that `If` statement and not run.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but how could I write it for I am very newbie in bash? Thank you.

Comment: Please read over [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on how to ask a good question well.

Answer (score 1):

`at` should do the trick. Based on `man at` and an offset variable `$offset` you should be able to use this (untested):

```
echo 'some_command with arguments' | at "now + ${offset}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I tried to use 'at' right away and faced that it executes the script immediately and not at a scheduled time as its mentioned ('a new job has been added'), so I couldn't understand why it didn't work for me and thought then it could be done with another methods.

Comment: That message just means `at` has *scheduled* the command to run at the given time.

Comment: I see but using 'at' the script runs at the time I execute it despite of the added scheduled job (it doesn't start at the pointed time though), maybe something wrong with my 'at' command on my computer, I can try it on another one to see if the problem is in command and not in the script. Thanks

Comment: tried to `open /Applications/Mail.app | at 08:27` and as I said it opened the app immediately, the same on both computers, what I do wrong? I need to run another working script at a time, not just a command. Thank you.

Comment: No, `at` is not broken. What you're doing there is running the command and passing the *output* of it to `at`, which is not at all what you want. Try using the pattern I've shown you.

Comment: `at 08:40 open /Applications/Mail.app/`

Comment: Ah, I was wrong about how to specify the job. See updated command.

Comment: Yes, it tells `job 53 at Tue Nov 13 08:47:00 2018` but at that scheduled time nothing happens

Comment: Then I would recommend either updating your question or adding a new one detailing what you've done, what happened, and what you expected to happen.

Comment: Oh, I had to read your update more carefully, it has run the command at the scheduled time, my mistake was in missing `echo` part! I will try the second part of the code you suggested 'at "now + ${offset}' later and tell if it works. Thank you!

Comment: All is ok except offset works only with `now` argument but the purpose is to use var $sunrise and add + 2 minutes to it. How could I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I described my task more detailed in Ask Different [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/393240/run-itunes-at-sunrises-using-bash). If you could comment it I'd be appreciated. Thanks.